# many a: distributive idiom

Tags: idioms, verb-agreement, semantics, logic

According to Garner's fourth edition, *there **is** many a person* is the correct verbal agreement because **many a** is *a distributive rather than aggregate* idiom.

What does the author refer to by the distinction *distributive vs aggregate* here?

Comment: Interesting question. I know what it means in mathematics but I can't quite see how to apply that here. Does the author not give any definitions of the terms used in his book?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK distributive adj.
Referring to things individually, not
collectively, so as to express separation
or emphasize individuality. •
Adjectives such as _each, either_, and
_every_.

Comment: Okay, I've made an answer on that basis.

Comment: 'There is many a person who thinks that O'Sullivan is the greatest snooker player ever' **not**  'There are many a person who think that O'Sullivan is the greatest snooker player ever'. 'Many a' relates to A, B, C, D ... **not** S = {A-Z}. Contrast 'There are many people who ...', referencing the whole 'Yes' lobby, S.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth what's _'Yes' lobby_ mean?

Comment: S; the complete set of those _agreeing_ with the sentiment.

Answer (score 1):

> **many a** is a distributive rather than aggregate idiom

*Many a* is distributive because it refers to things individually, just like *each*, *every* and *either*.

All of the above expressions can be followed by "one", e.g.

*Each one* was a perfect sphere.

*Every single one* of them was drunk out of their minds.

When it comes to shoes, you can put *either on*e on first.

There are lots of dogs in this area, in fact I've seen *many a one* without a collar or lead.

Comment: "When it comes to shoes, you can put _either one_ on first" I do not understand this one

Comment: Child: Mummy, which shoe should I put in first?  Mother: It doesn't matter dear. You can put either one on first.  The word "one" acts like a pronoun but refers to a single shoe.  Does that help?  The mother could have said, "You can put either shoe on first" but instead of repeating "shoe", she says "one."

Comment: Although shoes are plural, we understand *either one* refers to a single shoe. I would not put on my right shoes, only my right shoe.

Comment: @YosefBaskin _Although shoes are plural_, what do you exactly mean? the word _shoes_ is IN THE plural

Comment: GJC - I think both senses are possible. "shoes" is plural but shoes can be plural (if you have more than one shoe).

Comment: I mean that if you start with shoes (plural) and later refer to one (of them), the reader shifts from the *shoes* to the one *shoe* (either one) you are putting on. It's not perfect math, but it works.